# Java Code Questions

Tags: java

I want to implement a class which includes a student's name, their GPA, grade level, and their final score. We had to create a Tester along with the initial class creates 2 different students, prints their grade level, GPA, their name, and the calculated final test score.

Formula to calculate final test score = `.60 * written + .40 * handsOn`

Any help would be appreciated, I can't get this program down and I've been trying for quite a while now.

Here is my code:

Tester:

```
public class IntroToJavaTester
{

    public static void main()
    {

        IntroToJava j1 = new IntroToJava("Joe", 11, 3.2);

        System.out.println(j1.getName());
        System.out.println(j1.getGradeLevel());
        System.out.println(j1.getGPA());
        System.out.println(j1.getFinalScore(written, handsOn));

        IntroToJava j2 = new IntroToJava("Jim", 11, 3.2);

        System.out.println(j2.getName());
        System.out.println(j2.getGradeLevel());
        System.out.println(j2.getGPA());
        System.out.println(j2.getFinalScore( written,handsOn));
    }
}
```

Here is the IntroToJava class:

```
public class IntroToJava
{
    private String name;
    private int glev;
    private double gpa;
    private double finalscore;
    private double written = 80;
    private double handsOn = 90;

    public IntroToJava(String a, int b, double c, double d, double e)
    {
        name = a;
        glev = b;
        gpa = c;
        written = d;
        handsOn = e;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getGradeLevel()
    {
        return glev;
    }

    public double getGPA ()
    {
        return gpa;
    }

    public double getFinalScore(int written, int handsOn)
    {
        finalscore = .60*written+.40*handsOn;
        return finalscore;
    }


}
```

Comment: What is your question? Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: i can't see anything wrong.. except the fact `written, handsOn` don't exists in `IntroToJavaTester` class

Comment: debugger won't help with code that doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Your `IntroToJava` constructor is defined with 5 arguments and you're calling it with only 3 in `IntroToJavaTester`.

The two arguments you're omitting appear to correspond to the fields `written` and `handsOn`.

You've defined `getFinalScore` to take two arguments with the same names but a different type.

I suspect what you probably really want is for `getFinalScore` to take no arguments but use these two fields.

Or perhaps `getFinalScore` is supposed to just be a getter for the field `finalScore` which doesn't seem to be set or used anywhere, but has a suspiciously similar name.